# Flutter Firebase Auth + Firestore Provider user document

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, flutter-provider, flutter-navigation

A common scenario in nearly every single Flutter Firebase project is to use `authStateChanges` to determine logged in/out state by checking if the `User` object is null. But generally there are extra fields that are needed on a user, which come from Firestore. (I usually make a `FirestoreUser` model). It's generally really nice to be able to stream the current user's Firestore document and have it available throughout the app. But there's a few issues.

```
final user = context.read<User?>();

return StreamProvider<FirestoreUser?>(
  create: (_) => UserRepository(FirebaseFirestore.instance)
      .streamUser(user!.uid),
  initialData: null,
  child: const HomeScreen(),
);
```

StreamProvider's require an `initialData`. The end goal would be to use `context.watch<FirestoreUser>()` throughout the app, but since `User` (FirebaseAuth user) can be null, `FirestoreUser` (Firestore user) also has to be null.

```
final user = context.watch<FirestoreUser?>();
// this should technically never happen, but still need to check for it because it's impossible(?) to Provide a non-null FirestoreUser
if(user == null) return SizedBox.shrink();
...
return Text('Hello ${user.displayName}');
```

It would be super annoying if I had to do this on every. single. page. (This is going to be a large application)

The FirestoreUser should be available throughout the app, so it needs to be *above* MaterialApp. This makes the logged in/out logic complicated, since your login screen needs to be *below* MaterialApp.

I am also using MaterialApp.router using the Beamer package. They have a bunch of examples, but none of them are actually useful. Their FirebaseAuth example has everything in one widget and would never be a real world scenario.

Also, it's been a good while since null-safety was introduced but there are so few examples/tutorials out there that actually implement null-safety.

I'm convinced it is impossible to listen to authStateChanges to control logged in/out state and then *only* providing a non-null Firestore document to use throughout the application using `MaterialApp.router`. Is that asking too much? I feel like this would be the most common scenario. It's one I've been struggling with for my past 5+ apps.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented the same scenario with `MaterialApp.router`, I hope my solution helps you.

I set up a `ChangeNotifierProvider` to handle authentication state called `MyAuthState`. `MyAuthState` is placed above `MaterialApp.router`, I actually use more providers, so it looks like the following. For the navigation to be accessibly (e.g. route the user to login etc.) I add the `RouterDelegate` to the `ChangeNotifierProvider`:

```
MultiProvider(
  providers: [
    ChangeNotifierProvider(
        create: (context) => MyAuthState(
            routerDelegate: ...)),
    ...
  ],
  builder: (context, child) {
    return MaterialApp.router(
      ...
    );
  }
```

Then in `MyAuthState` I listen to Firebase Authentication state changes, save current authentication state and start the stream to listen to my own Firestore user collection if a user is authenticated. Something like:

```
StreamSubscription<MyUser?>? _myUserStream;

...

FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges().listen((User? firebaseUser) {
  // save authentication state to know whether a user is authenticated
  // if it is not null, start a stream

  _myUserStream = <stream to listen snapshots for my own user collection>;
  
  notifyListeners();
});
```

After this I use an authentication router as the home route of my application, consuming `MyAuthState` provider, and this will decide whether to show a login screen or something else (the code uses an enum for the different states):

```
class _MyAuthRouter extends State<MyAuthRouter> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<MyAuthState>(builder: (context, myAuthState, child) {
      switch (myAuthState.status) {

        // before first auth state => progress indicator
        case MyAuthStatus.unknown:
          return const CircularProgressIndicator();

        // user is logged out, not found or disabled => login screen
        case MyAuthStatus.loggedOut:
        case MyAuthStatus.notFound:
        case MyAuthStatus.disabled:
          return const MyAuthLogin();

        // email not verified => verify email screen
        case MyAuthStatus.emailUnverified:
          return const MyAuthVerifyEmail();

        // logged in => home screen
        case MyAuthStatus.loggedIn:
          return const MyPageHome();
      }
    });
  }
}
```

And since I only get to `MyPageHome` upon user is logged in, I know that the stream for my user collection will be available and I can use `context.read` or `context.watch` to get the user's data.

Comment: After taking another look at your solution I have a few questions. Is MyAuthLogin, MyAuthVerifyEmail, and MyPageHome all MaterialApp.router widgets? I also have many flows (welcome screens, login/registration, onboarding). Can you share your code for your authentication router please? Thanks!

Comment: @Nelson.b.austin These high level widgets serve as the `home` route for the application. Depending on auth status, one of these will be the `home` route. The rest of the routes are pushed with `Navigator`. Basically `/home` route is `const MyAuthRouter()`.

Comment: @Nelson.b.austin As I use Navigator 2.0, setting up routing is quite complicated, but you don't need Navigator 2.0 unless you are targeting web platform. The main thing is that depending on auth status your users will arrive to either login, or verify password, or home screen. From home they can navigate to the other routes.

Comment: I'm also using Navigator 2.0...kind of. I'm trying to use `go_router` or `beamer`